# Window is not defined for npm package okta-auth-js

Tags: javascript, node.js, okta

I'm trying to figure out how to do proper authorization flow for okta-auth-js for my company, but I'm getting a strange issue trying to run my sample code.

```
[okta-auth-sdk] WARN: Memory storage can only support simple single user use case on server side, please provide custom storageProvider or storageKey if advanced scenarios need to be supported.
file:///C:/Users/.../Documents/Workspace/okta/node_modules/@okta/okta-auth-js/esm/node/oidc/util/loginRedirect.js:41
    if (!isRedirectUri(window.location.href, sdk)) {
                       ^

ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at isLoginRedirect (file:///C:/Users/.../Documents/Workspace/okta/node_modules/@okta/okta-auth-js/esm/node/oidc/util/loginRedirect.js:41:24)
    at OktaAuth.start (file:///C:/Users/.../Documents/Workspace/okta/node_modules/@okta/okta-auth-js/esm/node/OktaAuth.js:230:25)
    at async file:///C:/Users/.../Documents/Workspace/okta/up-front.mjs:13:1
```

I assume this is something to do with me trying to run this as a es module and not just straight js?

This is my file for `up-front.mjs`

```js
import * as okta from '@okta/okta-auth-js';

const authClient = new okta.OktaAuth({
    issuer: 'https://.../oauth2/.../default',
    clientId: '...',
    clientSecret: '...',
    scopes: ['license:write'],
    cookies: {
        sessionCookie: true
    }
});

await authClient.start();

const result = await authClient.signInWithCredentials({
    username: '...',
    password: '...'
});

console.log(result);

await authClient.stop();
```

How do I define `window`?

### Update

According to comments, I used the documentation https://github.com/okta/okta-auth-js#node-js-and-react-native-usage to make the following changes:

`up-front.js`

```js
var OktaAuth = require('@okta/okta-auth-js').OktaAuth;

const authClient = new OktaAuth({
    issuer: 'https://.../oauth2/.../default',
    clientId: '...',
    clientSecret: '...',
    scopes: ['license:write'],
    cookies: {
        sessionCookie: true
    }
});

authClient.start().then(async () => {
    const result = await authClient.signInWithCredentials({
        username: '...',
        password: '...'
    });
    
    console.log(result);
    
    await authClient.stop();
});
```

I also tried using all `.then` and no awaits and it changed nothing

Comment: Is the snippet used in some web with something like react/angular/vue?

Comment: no, this is all it is, in the end it's intended to go in a smoke test

Comment: how are you executing it ? npm run start or directly in your web browser?

Comment: I just use `node ./up-front.mjs`

Comment: See this documentation for usage with Node: https://github.com/okta/okta-auth-js#node-js-and-react-native-usage

Comment: Okay, I made some modifications according to the documentation there, but I still get the same issue, I'll update the question with my changes

Comment: Did you documented about oauth2? What is your requirement? Secure the login of your web apps with okta? Secure your microservices? Secure your backend to backend systems? A mobile app?

Comment: the okta server is implemented by some other project, but the requirement is oauth2, and we have to use user credentials to login because the I think there's a requirement on the auth server that says we can't use client credentials? we're securing the whole system with okta at this point